# How can I make my modal draggable and scrollable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to javascript and other frameworks like angular JS and bootstrap. Below is my code code and i want my modal window to be draggable and scrollable.
How can i do this? Any help will be appreciated.

My HTML file looks like this:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script src="common/angularGrid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/angularGrid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/theme-fresh.css">

    <script src="js/blg.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="blgRows" ng-controller="blgRowsCtrl">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-blue">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header top-header">
                <a class="top-button" href="#"> <i class="fa fa-eraser"></i> Reset</a>
                <a class="top-button-selected" href={{blgUrl}} > <i class="fa fa-list-ol"></i> BLG</a>
                <a class="top-button" href={{qrepUrl}} target=_blank> <i class="fa fa-download"></i> QREP</a>
                <a class="top-button" href={{trialUrl}} target=_blank> <i class="fa fa-book"></i> Trial</a>
                <a class="top-button" href={{tbpUrl}} target=_blank> <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> TBP </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
  <div style="margin-top: 50px; width: 100%; background-color: #DDDDDD;">
        <div class="row grid-top">
            <div class="col-md-4">{{data.desc}} </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1">
                                    <a ng-click="trialSelectAll()">Select All</a>    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ng-click="trialCalRequest()">Apply Selected Posts To Trial</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="height: 85%; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; ">
                <div angular-grid="gridOptions" class="ag-fresh"></div>
         </div>
  </div>
        <modal title="Calculation Stats" visible="showModal">
            <div style="padding: 30px 20px 20px 20px; height: 55%; box-sizing: border-box;">
                <ul><b>Accounts for calculation:</b> {{calcInfo.accounts}}</ul>
                <ul>
                    <b>Range lines that were recalculated: </b>
                    <li ng-repeat="x in calcInfo.rangelines">
                       {{x.lineKey}} -> {{x.text}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <b>Calc lines that were recalculated: </b>
                    <li ng-repeat="x in calcInfo.calclines">
                       {{x.lineKey}} -> {{x.text}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul><b>Total Time: {{calcInfo.calcTime}}</b></ul>
            </div>
        </modal>
</body>
```

my js file contains...

```
module.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content modal-huge">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:true,

      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = attrs.title;

        scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
          if(value == true) {
            $(element).modal('show');

        } else {
            $(element).modal('hide');
        }
        });

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
          });
        });

        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
          });
        });

      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: have you used `draggable` of bootstrap modal?

Comment: try this : http://embed.plnkr.co/8CHoiN/preview

Comment: Thank you. I used  the embed.plnkr.co/8CHoiN/preview link to implement the draggable functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the http://plnkr.co/edit/cu1TVKCY8ucYcT2AScJb?p=preview to implement the draggable funcationlity to modal window.
Below code shows how did it to work.

```
module.directive('modal', function ($document) {    
return {
  template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
      '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
        '<div class="modal-content modal-huge">' + 
          '<div class="modal-header">' + 
            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
            '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' + 
          '</div>' + 
          '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
        '</div>' + 
      '</div>' + 
    '</div>',
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  replace:true,
  scope:true,

  link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.title = attrs.title;

    var startX = 0,
    startY = 0,
    x = 0,
    y = 0;


    element.css({

        position: 'fixed',
        cursor: 'move'
    });

    scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
      if(value == true) {
        $(element).modal('show');

    } else {
        $(element).modal('hide');
    }
    });

    $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
      scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
      });
    });

    $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
      scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
      });
    });


    $(element).on('mousedown', function (event) {

        // Prevent default dragging of selected content
        event.preventDefault();
        startX = event.screenX - x;
        startY = event.screenY - y;
        $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
        $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
        //$(element).on('mousemove', mousemove);
        //$(element).on('mouseup', mouseup);

    });

    function mousemove(event) {
        y = event.screenY - startY;
        x = event.screenX - startX;
        //element.css({
        element.css({
            top: y + 'px',
            left: x + 'px'
        });
    }

    function mouseup() {
        $document.unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
        $document.unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
        //$(element).unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
        //$(element).unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
    }

  }
};
```

});

Thank you.